# When does static initialization happen?

Tags: java, static, initialization

When are static fields initialized? If I never instantiate a class, but I access a static field, are ALL the static blocks and private static methods used to instantiate private static fields called (in order) at that instant?

What if I call a static method? Does it also run all the static blocks? Before the method?

Comment: Similar for static initializer blocks: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007666/in-what-order-do-static-initializer-blocks-in-java-run

Answer (score 169, accepted):

A class's static initialization normally happens immediately before the first time one of the following events occur:

- an instance of the class is created,
- a static method of the class is invoked,
- a static field of the class is assigned,
- a non-constant static field is used, or
- <strike>for a top-level class, an assert statement lexically nested within the class is executed</strike><sup>1</sup>.

See [JLS 12.4.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1).

It is also possible to force a class to initialize (if it hasn't already initialized) by using [`Class.forName(fqn, true, classLoader)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.ClassLoader)) or the short form [`Class.forName(fqn)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String))

---

> When does static class initialization happen?

See above.

> When are static fields initialized?

As part of static class initialization; see above.

> If I never instantiate a class, but I access a static field, are ALL the static blocks and private static methods used to instantiate private static fields called (in order) at that instant?

Yes.  (Modulo that nothing is truly instantaneous.)

> What if I call a static method? Does it also run all the static blocks? Before the method?

Yes and yes.

---

Note that it is possible to construct code where you can observe the *default initialized* value of a static field.

---

<sup>1 - The final bullet point was present in the JLS for Java 6 through Java 8, but it was apparently a mistake in the specification.  It was finally corrected in the Java 9 JLS: see [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47999746/2844702).</sup>

Comment: There is a common pitfall though. Primitives and `String`s are substituted and not referenced. If you reference a `class Other { public static final int VAL = 10; }` from some class `MyClass { private int = Other.VAL; }`, the class `Other` will not be loaded. Instead, the compiler will simply substitute the final field at compile time.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter - yes ... that is the **constant** static field case.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter, this is not true for all 'static final' primitive or `String` variables, only ones initialized by a constant expression.

Comment: Yes, and the field does not even need to be `static` while this is common case.

Comment: @StephenC is it also true regarding Androi with Java development?

Comment: It is the same programming language.  Yes.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter but when the field is not `static`, you need a reference to an instance of it (the compiler will embed a `null`-check even when using the constant value afterwards), so reading a non-`static` constant field will not trigger a class initialization, but the initialization has happen already anyway, when the instance was created (if not even earlier)

Answer (score 17):

Static fields are initialized during the [initialization](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4) "phase" of the class loading (loading, linking and initialization) that includes static initializers and initializations of its static fields. The static initializers are executed in a textual order as defined in the class.

Consider the example:

```
public class Test {

   static String sayHello()  {
      return a;
   }

   static String b = sayHello(); // a static method is called to assign value to b.
                                 // but its a has not been initialized yet.

   static String a = "hello";

   static String c = sayHello(); // assignes "hello" to variable c

    public static void main(String[] arg) throws Throwable {
         System.out.println(Test.b); // prints null
         System.out.println(Test.sayHello()); // prints "hello"
    }
}
```

The Test.b prints `null` because when the `sayHello` was called in static scope, the static variable `a` was not initialized.

Comment: Strictly speaking, initialization is not a "phase" of class loading.  Indeed, some classes *may* be loaded but never initialized if the application doesn't actually make use of them.

Comment: @Stephen C You are right, I used it for a lack of a better term, maybe i'll quote it.

Comment: @StephenC does that mean while the Class loading takes place, it assigns memory to static variables (& methods) but those static variables aren't initialized with values provided in code? 
because here it seemd when b->sayHello()->a, 'a' is in memory but value to it  is yet not assigned.

Comment: Basically, yes.

Comment: @StephenC please, could you give some details? As I know in the linking phase it allocates memory for static variables and assigns them a default value. Then in the initialization phase, it assigns them with original values. In this example, `b` is null, because in the initialization phase static blocks are executed from parent to child and from top to bottom.

Comment: You have got it correct.  I don't know why you want me to explain something you already understand.  (But it is not *just* the static blocks.  All static initializations are executed in order, from the start of the class.  Like the answer says.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, all static initializers are run before you access class first time. If it was any other way, I would call it a bug.

Comment: There are ways to refer to a class without initializing it.