# How the construction function runs when call static function in Java

Tags: java

I want a class to check if an input is valid, and all the valid input is record in a text file.

So in construction, it read in the text file and put all valid inputs into a HashSet. Then I have `static` function to receive an input and check if the input is in the HashSet.

Code structure is like following:

```
public class Validator {
    HashSet validInputs;

    public Validator() {
        //read in
    }

    public static boolean validate(String in) {
        //check and return
    }
}
```

Then in other class, I need to use `Validator` class to validate strings. Code is like:

```
...
String a = XXX;
boolean valid = Validator.validate(a);
...
```

I haven't tested the code, but I have two questions:

1. Does it work? Is the valid input text file read in?
2. When will the class read in the text file?
3. Will `Validator` read the text file every time I call the function `validate()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a singleton and a *non-static* `validate`-method:

```
public class Validator {
    private static Validator instance = null;

    /**
     * Do not use new Validator; use Validator.getInstance() instead.
     */
    private Validator() {
        // read in
    }

    public static Validator getInstance() {
        if(instance == null) {
            instance = new Validatorr();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public boolean validate(String str) {
        // check and return
    }
}
```

Everywhere where you need to `validate` something use:

```
Validator.getInstance().validate()
```

*NOTE: A side effect of the singleton pattern implemented this way is that if the Validator is not used, the Validator is **not** created and `in` is not read.  This may or may not be what you want.*

Answer (score 5):

> Does it work? Is the valid input text file read in?

No, that won't work.

Your method should be an instance method so that it can access other instance members.

```
public boolean validate(String in) {
    //check and return
}
```

---

> When will the class read in the text file?

You have to construct the class before you can use it. The text file is read in the constructor.

---

> Will Validator read the text file every time I call the function validate()?

No. The constructor is called when you call `new Validator()`.

Answer (score 1):

It won't. `validInputs` will be tied to an instance of `Validator` and you won't be able to reference it from within a static method. What you need is a static block:

```
public final class Validator {
    private static HashSet validInputs;

    private Validator() {}

    static {
        //read in
    }

    public static boolean validate(String in) {


     //check and return
    }
}
```

If you do it this way:

```
When will the class read in the text file? -  When the class is loaded by the Class loader.
Will Validator read the text file every time I call the function validate()? -  No, only when the class is loaded.
```

Comment: isn't the static block only performed if, the classloader loads the class?

Comment: @duffy356 see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/java-static-class-initialization) post.

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't be able to access your `validInputs` until you create an instance of `Validator` using `new Validator()`

1. No, your file won't be read in at the time of use.
2. The file will be read when you create a new instance of `Validator`.
3. No. It will only be read in when you have `new Validator()`.

If you wish to be able to access this method staticly, consider using a [`Singleton`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).