# in what order are static blocks and static variables in a class executed?

Tags: java, static, final

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java static class initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/java-static-class-initialization)

Why is the string variable updated in the initialization block and not the integer(even though the block is written first)

```
class NewClass
{
    static 
    {
       System.out.println(NewClass.string+" "+NewClass.integer);
    }

    final static String string="static";
    final static Integer integer=1;

    public static void main(String [] args)//throws Exception
    {
    }
}
```

My output is

```
static null
```

P.S:Also noticed that string variable initialization happens before the block only when i insert the final modifier. why is that?why not for integer as well?I have declared it as final static too

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: How is this a duplicate of given link?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [section 12.4.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) of the JLS, snipped appropriately:

> The procedure for initializing C is then as follows:
>
> - Then, initialize the final class variables and fields of interfaces whose values are compile-time constant expressions (§8.3.2.1, §9.3.1, §13.4.9, §15.28).
> - Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

So for non-compile-time-constants, it's not a case of "all variables" and then "all static initializers" or vice versa - it's all of them together, in textual order. So if you had:

```
static int x = method("x");

static {
    System.out.println("init 1");
}

static int y = method("y");

static {
    System.out.println("init 2");
}

static int method(String name) {
    System.out.println(name);
    return 0;
}
```

Then the output would be:

```
x
init 1
y
init 2
```

Even making `x` or `y` final wouldn't affect this here, as they still wouldn't be compile-time constants.

> P.S:Also noticed that string variable initialization happens before the block only when i insert the final modifier.

At that point, it's a compile-time constant, and any uses of it basically inlined. Additionally, the variable value is assigned before the rest of the initializers, as above.

[Section 15.28](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28) of the JLS defines compile-time constants - it includes all primitive values and `String`, but *not* the wrapper types such as `Integer`.

Comment: i am sorry.still confused.what makes string a compile time constant and why isn't integer the same?

Comment: @TariqIbrahim: I'll edit a link into the answer.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a short and straight forward answer to you question....

`static Variable` :

static Variables are executed when the `JVM` **loads** the `Class`, and the `Class` **gets loaded when** either its been **instantiated** or its `static method` is being called.

`static Block or static Initializer Block` :

static static Initializer Block gets Initialized **before** the `Class` gets **instantiated** or **before** its `static method` is called, and **Even before** its `static variable` is used.

**///////// Edited Part /////////**

```
class NewClass {

    final static String string = "static";
    final static Integer integer = 1;

    static {
        System.out.println(NewClas.string + " " + NewClas.integer);
    }

    public static void main(String [] args) { // throws Exception
        new NewClas();
    }

}
```

**The above will print** `static 1`.

The reason is that the `JVM` will do the **optimization process** known as `Constant folding`, doing an pre-calculation of the constant variables.

Moreover in **your case the result** was `static null` cause `Constant folding` is applied to Primitive type and not Wrapper Object, in your case its Integer...

Comment: in that case the block should print static 1 right?

Comment: thank you.this helped clear a lot of things]

Answer (score 1):

They are initialized in the given order (fields and static blocks), that's why printed value is `null`, nothing was assigned to static fields that are defined after the static block.