# Order of static variable initialization, Java

Tags: java, static

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java static class initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/java-static-class-initialization)
>   [in what order are static blocks and static variables in a class executed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448465/in-what-order-are-static-blocks-and-static-variables-in-a-class-executed)

When I run this code the answer is 1, I thought it would be 2. 
What is the order of initialization and the value of k in each step?

```java
public class Test {

    static {k = 2;}
    static int k = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

Edit 1: As a follow up to "k is set to default value" then why this next code doesn't compile? Theres an error "Cannot reference a field before it's defined".

```java
public class Test {

    static {System.out.println(k);}
    static int k=1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

Edit 2: For some unknow to me reason it^ works when instead of "k" its "Test.k".

Thanks for all the answers. this will sufice :D

Comment: First, k will be assigned default value, then from top, the static code will be run and 2 will be assigned, then 1 will be assigned. Then main function is called and print out k. `static int k = 1` is effectively `static int k;` declaration, then `static { k = 1; }`

Comment: @KennyTM Yes, if I had run it the way like in that post You paste, I would know whats going on.

Comment: @nhahtdh Will k be assigned default value? Then why this code doesn't comiple: public class Test {

 
 static {System.out.println(k);k=2;}
 static int k ;
 

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(k);
 }
}

Comment: @Hoto: (Use `Test.k` to print it). I don't have enough knowledge to explain the whole picture. From [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2): 1) final fields will be initialized according to the initializers 2) static initializer and static blocks will be run according to text order (before the block is run, the static field will have default value)

Comment: A test program to demonstrate my point: http://ideone.com/GiArqV and about [initial value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)

Comment: @nhahtdh Thanks. Now I have to find why it only works with "Test.k" ;) Anyway You should start answering with an "answer" not a "comment". Your answers were the best and the fastest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are executed in the order that you write them. If the code is:

```
public class Test {

    static int k = 1;
    static {k = 2;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(k);
    }

}
```

then the output becomes 2.

The order of initialization is: [..the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class..., in textual order, as though they were a single block.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2)

And the values (for your code) are: k = 0 (default), then it's set to 2, then it's set back to 1.

You can check that it's actually set to 2 by running the following code:

```
private static class Test {

    static {
        System.out.println(Test.k);
        k = 2;
        System.out.println(Test.k);
        }
    static int k = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats not what I meant in my question. I wanted the order of initialization and values of k in each step.

Comment: Ok, I added a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Yeah... but now theres a bit of a chaos in Your answer xD

Comment: Is k EVER set to default value? This code does not comiple: public class Test {

 
 static {System.out.println(k);k=2;}
 static int k ;
 

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(k);
 }
}

Comment: This one does: `public class Test { static {System.out.println(Test.k);k=2;} static int k ; public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println(k); } }`

Comment: Good one my friend :D So it does have an initial value of 0.

Answer (score 5):

**Short answer**

When the initialization of the class starts, `k` will have initial value of 0.

The static block (since it precedes the assignment in the declaration) is then executed, and `k` will be assigned 2.

Then the initializer in the declaration is executed, and `k` will be assigned 1.

**Long explanation**

Let us use [this example](http://ideone.com/O7rPiD), since your example is a bit simple:

```
class TestInitOrder {
  static {
    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.stat1);
    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.stat2);
    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.str);
    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.str2);

    str = "something";

    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.str);
    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.str2);
    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.lazy);
    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.second);
  }

  private static final int stat1 = 10;
  static final String str2 = "sdfff";
  static String str = "crap";
  private static int stat2 = 19;
  static final Second second = new Second();
  static final int lazy;

  static {
    lazy = 20;
  }

  static {
    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.str2);
    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.stat2);
    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.str);
    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.lazy);
    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.second);
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
  }

}

class Second {
  public Second() {
    System.out.println(TestInitOrder.second);
  }
}
```

According to [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), from [section 4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5):

> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is used:
>
> - Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created

(The following lines from the specification specify the default value for all the types, basically some form of 0, such as `0`, `0.0d`, `null`, `false`, etc.)

So before the class is initialized (due to one of [these reasons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1)), the variables will hold an initial value.

According to the [detailed initialization procedure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2) (only the interesting steps are quoted here, and emphasis mine):

> 6.
>   [...] Then, initialize the **`final` class variables** and **fields of interfaces** whose values are ***compile-time***  **constant expressions** (§8.3.2.1, §9.3.1, §13.4.9, §15.28).
>
> [...]
>
> 9.
>   Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

Let us look at step 6, with the 4 `final` class variables: `stat1`, `str2`, `second`, `lazy`.

Since `10` is constant expression, and so is `"sdfff"`, and due to the order of execution, it is not possible to *observe* the initial value for `str2` and `stat1`. In order to make an observation, the earliest you can do is in step 9.

The case of `second` demonstrate that when the right hand side is not a compile-time constant expression, so its initial value is visible.

The case of `lazy` is different, since the assignment is done in static block, and hence happen in step 9 - so it is possible to observe its initial value. (Well, the compiler checks carefully that `lazy` is assigned exactly once).

---

After the initialization of final class variables with compile-time constant expression comes the execution of static blocks and the rest of the initializers.

As you can see from the example, the static blocks and initialization happens according to textual order - demonstrated with the use of `str` variable - it is first printed out as `null`, then `something`, then `crap`.

Comment: @EJP: Note that 2 conditions 1) **final** class variables and 2) initializer is compile-time constant that is done in step 6. No contradiction here. You can even check out the program on ideone.