# Java : Why does placement of static variable matter?

Tags: java, static

The following example defines 2 static variables. 
Variable 1 (myBoolean1) is defined above the MySingletonExample (instance) variable.

Variable 2 (myBoolean2) is defined below the MySingletonExample (instance) variable.

Both variables are set to **true** but only 1 variable (myBoolean1) shows the proper value when displayed.

```
public class MySingletonExample 
{

    //static volatile boolean  myBoolean1 = false;
    static boolean  myBoolean1 = false;

    private static volatile MySingletonExample instance = new MySingletonExample();

    //static volatile boolean  myBoolean2 = false;
    static boolean  myBoolean2 = false;


    private MySingletonExample()
    {
        myBoolean1 = true;
        myBoolean2 = true;
    }

    protected static MySingletonExample getInstance() 
    {
        System.out.println("myBoolean1 = " + myBoolean1);
        System.out.println("myBoolean2 = " + myBoolean2);
        return instance;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        MySingletonExample.getInstance();
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        MySingletonExample.getInstance();
    }

}
```

When executed, this is the output.

myBoolean1 = true

myBoolean2 = false

myBoolean1 = true

myBoolean2 = false

Why doesn't myBoolean2 return true instead of false like myBoolean1?

The only different is the placement. Is there a "rule" when working with static variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order of static variable initialization, Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13554507/order-of-static-variable-initialization-java)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`myBoolean2` is set back to false after being set to true in the constructor, due to the order of static variable initialization.

> Is there a "rule" when working with static variables?

Yes. A static singleton doesn't need static state. Just make them regular fields.

```
private static volatile MySingletonExample instance = new MySingletonExample();

private final boolean myBoolean1;
private final boolean myBoolean2;

private MySingletonExample()
{
    myBoolean1 = true;
    myBoolean2 = true;
}

//...
```

Singleton is an antipattern, but if you feel you must use it, [implement it using an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26285520/implementing-singleton-with-an-enum-in-java).

Answer (score 5):

All the statics in the block get executed in-order.  So first `myBoolean1` is set to `false`, then comes the call to the `MySingletonExample()` constructor, which sets `myBoolean1` and `myBoolean2` to `true`.  Finally, `myBoolean2` is set to `false`.

There needs to be some deterministic order in which they get invoked, otherwise it would be impossible to reason about the behavior of the program.