# Java static method vs main static method

Tags: java, static-methods, program-entry-point

I'm having trouble understanding the following code's execution. I want to follow the Java program so that I can understand how everything works together. I step up breakpoints in Eclipse but it doesn't explain why. Here's the code:

```
public class Sequence {
    public Sequence() {
        System.out.print("c ");
    }

    {
        System.out.print("y "); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Sequence().go();
    }

    void go() {
        System.out.print("g ");
    }

    static {
        System.out.print("x ");
    }
}
```

The output to the code is `x y c g`. Can someone explain why this is? I thought the program entry point was `public static void main` but it appears `static` executes first?

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: What don't you understand? The `static` block? It is not a method (in the source), it is an **initialization** block, ie. happens first.

Comment: I thought the program would print `c` first but it prints out `x`. I don't understand why.

Comment: possible duplicate of [in what order are static blocks and static variables in a class executed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448465/in-what-order-are-static-blocks-and-static-variables-in-a-class-executed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `static` block is executed before the `main` starts, so `x` get printed.

Then we enter the main, and we call

```
new Sequence().go();
```

Which calls the `Sequence` constructor. As per the *static* block, *before* The `Sequence` constructor gets called (so before a new `Sequence` object gets initialized), the instance block (the one written within the braces) gets executed, so `y` gets printed.

Then the constructor call prints `c`.

In the end, the `go()` method gets called on the newly created object, so `g` gets printed.

So the full output will be

```
x y c g
```

Answer (score 2):

The JLS is of help here, [chapter 12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html) to be precise.

First the `static` block will run. This will happen when the class is loaded by the `ClassLoader`.

Then `main` will run, this is executed by the JVM to start the application.

Then your constructor is executed when you call `new Sequence()`. The compiler will yank your instance initialiser (the bit in curly brackets) into the top of the constructor (after the implicit call to to the superclass constructor). So the bit in curly brackets runs first then the code in the constructor.

Finally the method `go()` is called.

So the output of the code is `x y c g`

Answer (score 1):

In your class you have used

```
//constructor
    public Sequence() {
        System.out.print("c ");
    }

    //instance init block
    {
        System.out.print("y "); 
    }

    //method
    void go() {
        System.out.print("g ");
    }

    //static init block
    static {
        System.out.print("x ");
    }
```

-> Init blocks execute in the order they appear.

->Static init blocks run once, when the class is first loaded.

-> Instance init blocks run every time a class instance is created.

-> Instance init blocks run after the constructor's call to super().

->Constructor run after when you create an instance.

According all of that rules you got,as expected `x y c g`  output

Answer (score 1):

Java execute static block after class loading and before any method. Main method is entry point for any program but it is however a method then static class initialization.

Answer (score 1):

First jvm loads static blocks when application starts. So static block executed first.
 Then main method  execution starts.

```
{
        System.out.print("y "); 
 }
```

is the constructor block it will be copied to each constructor so when u instantiate class it will be called every time.
   Click [here](http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/static-blocks.php)

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

i. When class is loaded then static block is executed first.

ii. Every time object of that class  is instantiated then initialization block
      i.e.

```
 {
   System.out.print("y ");
 }

 is executed(every time) and after that the time of constructor comes to be executed.
```

iii. When object creation is finished  then go() method is executed.
     And hence the output.