# Is there any reason to have several initializer/static blocks other than readability?

Tags: java, static, block

Non-static, or initializer blocks, [get copied into every constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).

Static blocks are [executed together, in textual order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12448494/1420898).

So, besides readability, is there any reason to have several of these blocks?

Comment: Static blocks can serve as scope for local variables. So you cannot generally simply concatenate the code. It depends if you take that for a readability feature.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are asking. Why would we have more than one static or not-static initializer blocks? AFAIK - no particular reason, @halfbit I don't think that variable scope affects that. Or why would we have static and non-static initializer blocks? This IS scope related, but I hope that you know the difference between static and instance variables already.

Comment: @Gemann Arlington I was writing about _local_ variables not instance variables or class variables. BTW: As i read it, the question is about having multiple `static { ... }` sections.

Comment: @halfbit Yes, having multiple `static {...}` blocks, but also multiple non-static `{...}` blocks.