# Static final int v/s static int

Tags: java, static, final

This problem was taken from my `Java test` study guide. Could some explain why this is the way that it is?

This code prints out the number 5 and not 12. Could you explain why? Could you explain why it would print out 12 if the second variable was also `final`, and 0 if neither of them were `final`?

```
public class Question26 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Q26.q26.ans);
    }
}

class Q26 {
    public static Q26 q26 = new Q26();
    public int ans;
    private static final int var1 = 5;
    private static int var2 = 7;

    public Q26() {
        ans = var1 + var2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at some of the `related` questions on the right.

Comment: static initialization order matters here

Comment: I _do_ hope that in your guide, this is quoted among things not to do? The only benefit of such a class is to shatter your brain to pieces for no benefit, since you will certainly not use such constructs in any real programming...

Comment: It's for a test. Of course it's meant to shatter my brain into little pieces for no benefit.

Comment: I don't get it too. But I think it's related to declaring a new instance of the class (which is non-static) as a static field.. if you create new Q26 in the main method, the output is 12, regardless whether final is used for the two variables.

Comment: @devnull : Why this question is duplicate of that?

Comment: @devnull Not only is the question different than the one you linked in concept, but the attribute being discussed is different: this question is about `final` vs not `final`; the one you linked is about `static` vs not `static`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

One thing to know where you declare `static` fields is that those are initialized in order; you cannot write:

```
public class DoesNotCompile
{
    private static final int foo = 1 + bar; // ERROR: bar is not defined
    private static final int bar = 1;
```

In your situation, however, things are a little different:

```
class Q26 {
    // Declared first, but NOT first to be initialized...
    public static Q26 q26 = new Q26();
    public int ans;
    // The honor befalls to this one, since it is declared `final`
    private static final int var1 = 5;
    private static int var2 = 7; // zero until initialized

    public Q26() {
        ans = var1 + var2;
    }
}
```

The default value of a non initialized `int` is 0; since your `Q26` instance is declared before `var1` and `var2`, **but** since `var1` is initialized first (since it is `final`), the result is what you see: `ans` is 5.

An equivalent to this code could be:

```
class Q26 {
    public static Q26 q26;
    private static final int var1;
    private static int var2;

    static {
        var1 = 5;
        q26 = new Q26();
        var2 = 7;
    }

    public int ans;

    public Q26() {
        ans = var1 + var2;
    }
}
```

Further note: there are also static initialization blocks; and order matters for these as well. You cannot do:

```
public class DoesNotCompileEither
{
    static {
        foo = 3; // ERROR: what is foo?
    }
    private static final int foo;
```

If you put the static initializer *below* the declaration of `foo`, then this will compile:

```
public class ThisOneCompiles
{
    private static final int foo; // declared
    static {
        foo = 3; // initialized
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a citation to the effect that `static final` variables are computed at compile time? I don't believe that's the case - the initialization can be deferred to a `static` block: `class Question26{ private static final int var1; static { var1 = 5; } }`. Deferring to a static block, the final calculation can still be changed.

Comment: I do mention this case in the answer

Comment: You should complete your answer by explaining what would happen if the `static` block was after the declaration of the `static` variable.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis done. I am still not 100% satisfied with the answer though.

Comment: You're only missing the explanation of what happens then. What @Richard was getting at was what if the `Q26.var1` variable was initialized in a `static` block that came after the declaration of `q26`. What would happen and why, obviously.

Comment: Uuuh, wait; if you declare `static final int foo = 4; static { foo = 5 };`, that is a compile error (note: in this order, of course)

Comment: But what if you left out the initialization expression at the declaration of `foo`?

Comment: Then it would compile, yes. But what is your point ultimately?

Comment: See Richard's answer. My point is that in that case, `var1` would have a value of `0` when the constructor executes. You should highlight the order of execution on class initialization.

Answer (score 6):

The static members on your class don't all magically initialize at the same time. Under the hood, Java has to set them - and it's doing it in the order you declared them, with exception of the `final` one.

Lets re-write that so the issue becomes clearer:

```
public class Question26 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Q26.q26.ans);
    }
}
class Q26 {
    public static Q26 q26;
    public int ans;
    private static final int var1 = 5;
    private static int var2;

    static {
        q26 = new Q26();
        var2 = 7;
    }

    public Q26() {
        ans = var1 + var2;
    }
}
```

Here the declaration of non-`final static` members and their initialization have been separated. Putting the initialization in a static block makes it a little more evident that the initialization of those members is code like any other and has an order of execution.

But why is the `final` variable initialized before `q26`? Looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12448494/248129) and at the [Java specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2), it seems that `var1` might be getting treated as a [compile-time constant expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). Even if it isn't being treated as such though, so long as it is declared and is initialized in one statement, `var1` should be initialized by the runtime before the non-`final` variables:

> At run time, static fields that are final and that are initialized with constant expressions are initialized first. This also applies to such fields in interfaces. These fields are "constants" that will never be observed to have their default initial values, even by devious programs.

Citation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.1

So what if we get crazy, separating the declaration and initialization of the `static final` member `var1`? In that case we could actually make your program compile and execute, only to output `0` - which contradicts some of the assertions you made in your question.

```
public class Question26 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Q26.q26.ans);
    }
}
class Q26 {
    public static Q26 q26;
    public int ans;
    private static final int var1;
    private static int var2;

    static {
        q26 = new Q26();
        var1 = 5;
        var2 = 7;
    }

    public Q26() {
        ans = var1 + var2;
    }
}
```

So don't be fooled into thinking the keywords you use to declare variables ensures some specific execution order!

Comment: Ah, Richard. I don't like your wording. `But why is the final variable initialized out of order?` It's not. From the JLS, `Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.`

Answer (score 3):

That is because of the order of initialization of static members, they will be initialized the textual order which they declared. Define the int variables `var1` and `var2` before that object variable `q26` like below

```
class Q26 {
    private static final int var1 = 5;
    private static int var2 = 7;
    public static Q26 q26 = new Q26();
    public int ans;


    public Q26() {
        ans = var1 + var2;
    }
}
```

**Now Output is 12**

In your case, the object `q26` was initialized before the variable `var2`, but `var1` is a final vaiable, the value is know at compile time. So you got that answer

Answer (score 1):

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

> If a primitive type or a string is defined as a constant and the
>   value is known at compile time, the compiler replaces the constant
>   name everywhere in the code with its value. This is called a
>   compile-time constant. If the value of the constant in the outside
>   world changes (for example, if it is legislated that pi actually
>   should be 3.975), you will need to recompile any classes that use this
>   constant to get the current value.

Therefore despite the fact of having that variable defined after the static `q26`, the compiler had replaced  each place `var1` appeared as 5.