# Why do fields seem to be initialized before constructor?

Tags: java, output

```
public class Dog {

 public static Dog dog = new Dog();
 static final int val1 = -5;
 static int val2 = 3;
 public int val3;

 public Dog() {
      val3 = val1 + val2;
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Dog.dog.val3);
}
}
```

The output is `-5`

From this result, it seems that the initialization of `val2` is before the completion of `dog` member and its instantiating.

Why is this order like this?

Comment: It could be that final fields are declared first (maybe because they are stored differently in the java bytecode) and non-final fields are declared after that in the order you wrote them. If this is right, then `val1` would be -5 at the point the `Dog` instance is declared, but val2 is still set to the default of 0.

Comment: It is because final variable are loaded first when class loading and then remaining static variables in order in which they are declared. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448465/in-what-order-are-static-blocks-and-static-variables-in-a-class-executed for more clarification

Comment: *final* int makes the int a *compile-time* constant.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you move your dog instance in the end, you may find the output becomes -2

```
public class Dog {

     static final int val1 = -5;// This is final, so will be initialized at compile time 
     static int val2 = 3;
     public int val3;

     public static Dog dog = new Dog();//move to here
 
     public Dog() {
          val3 = val1 + val2;
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Dog.dog.val3);//output will be -2
    }
}
```

**The final fields(whose values are compile-time constant expressions) will beinitialized first**, and then the rest will be executed at in textual order.

So , in your case when dog instance is initialized, `static int val2`(0) is not initialized yet, while `static final int val1`(-5) does since it is final.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/execution.html#12.4.2 states that:

> execute either the class variable initializers and static
> initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface,
> **in textual order**, as though they were a single block, **except that
> final class variables and fields of interfaces whose values are
> compile-time constants are initialized first**

---

## Updated a newer doc

Here is the jdk7 version from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2

final field is at step6:

> Then, initialize the final class variables and fields of interfaces
> whose values are compile-time constant expressions

while static field is at step 9:

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static
> initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface,
> in textual order, as though they were a single block.

Comment: Thanks, you give the official reference which is what I expect.

Answer (score 10):

Variable declaration sequence. The `static final int val1` is initialized first because it is a constant. However `static int val2` is still `0` at the time `public static Dog dog = new Dog();` is instantiated.

Answer (score 6):

What is happening..

The first line that is executing is this `public static Dog dog = new Dog();`.
Now, there are 2 things that must be kept in mind.

1. `final int` makes it a *compile* time constant. So, `-5` is already *hard-coded* into your code.
2. The call to new `Dog()` is done and the constructor is called which sets the value to `0` + `-5` = `-5`.

change `val2` to `final` then you will see the difference (you will get `-2` as answer.)

Note : static fields are initialized as and how they are encountered.

Answer (score 4):

Initialization sequence in your test;

1. `static final int val1 = -5;`           //constant as static final
2. `public static Dog dog = new Dog();`    //then 'dog' is initialize but its member val2 has not been initialized
3. `static int val2 = 3;`                 //at last 'val2' is initialized

This code change will output `-2`;

```
public class Dog {

     //public static Dog dog = new Dog();
     static final int val1 = -5;
     static int val2 = 3;
     public int val3;
     public static Dog dog = new Dog();     //moved here

     public Dog() {
          val3 = val1 + val2;
     }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Dog.dog.val3);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

All static variables are initialized in a separate static constructor, which is executed on class loading. In the same order as they apear in the code. Your example is compiled into something like this:

```
public class Dog {

 public static Dog dog;
 static final int val1 = -5;
 static int val2;
 public int val3;

 static {
  dog = new Dog();
  val2 = 3;
 }

 public Dog() {
      val3 = val1 + val2;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println(Dog.dog.val3);
 }
}
```

That's why order of class/instance variables matters. Class constructor execution happens at the end of initialization. Constants are resolved before. For more information refer to [Creation of New Class Instances](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5).

Comment: Your example explains my program well, but I wonder if there is an official explanation about your argument "All static variables are initialized in a separate static constructor.."