# Static Block and Static memory initialization and implementation

Tags: java, static, block

here i have written java program

```
    public class Main {
    static int i=2000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("value of j inside main "+j);

    }

    static {
        m1();
        System.out.print("value of i inside static block "+i);
    }


    static void m1() {
        System.out.print("inside static method");
        System.out.print("value of j inside static block "+j);
    }
    static int j =3000;




   }
```

inside static block, the value of i is printed as 2000, but value of j can't be referred in static block?
and value of j printing in m1() method is 0, but j is initialized then why is it printing 0?
why j cant be referred in static and it is referred in m1() which is first called by static block?
and inside main, value of j is printing as 3000?
so can anyone tell me what is wrong i am understanding here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output from your current code:

```
inside static method value of j inside static block 0
value of i inside static block 2000
value of j inside main 3000
```

Static blocks in a Java class are evaluated in the order in which they appear.  This means that when the static block making the `m1()` method call executes, `j` has not yet been assigned a value yet, so its value is reported as zero.  On the other hand, `i` has already been assigned the value `2000`, so it reports the value you expect.

Answer (score 0):

This is "Illegal forward reference" which means that you are trying to use a variable before it is defined. So you can move `static int j =3000;` before static block.

Comment: But i am referring j before defining in m1(), then how's it possible? I can't refer in static block but can refer in m1() method

Comment: @AnujPatel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12448465/in-what-order-are-static-blocks-and-static-variables-in-a-class-executed