# Exactly at what time static block or method is invoked

Tags: java

Below is a program in which there are two static block which in my opinion should be called at first notice but in order from top to bottom but that does not happen

```
public class StaticTest {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        A a1 = new A();  
        A a2 = new A();  
        B b1 = new B();  
    }
}  

class A {  
    static {  
        System.out.println("Static block of Class A");  
    }  
    {  
        System.out.println("Non-Static block of a instance of Class A");  
    }  
    public A() {  
        System.out.println("Constructing object of type A");  
    }  
}  
class B {  
    static {  
        System.out.println("Static block of Class B");  
    }
    {  
        System.out.println("Non-Static block of a instance of Class B");  
    }
    public B() {  
        System.out.println("Constructing object of type A");  
    }  
}
```

Comment: There are no static methods in that example (except for `main`).

Comment: Can you explain what happens exactly and why it does not meet your expectations?

Comment: Do necessary research and than post your question.There are lots of question regarding static blocks.

Comment: looks like a certification exam question... :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java static class initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/java-static-class-initialization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Exactly at what time static block or method is invoked*" - For question like this, the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html) has the answer for you.

[Static initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7):

> A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the class is
>   initialized. Together with any field initializers for class
>   variables, static initializers may be used to initialize the
>   class variables of the class.

By running your code, you can easily figure out what runs first.

Answer (score 2):

The static block in `class B` is not executed until `B` is actually needed. This is only the case in the 3rd statement of the main method. In fact, if you replace that line with

```
if (2*2 == 5) new B();
```

you'll notice that the static block of `B` is never executed, because B will not even be loaded.

To trace class loading, use the `-verbose:class` option of the java command.

Answer (score 1):

This is the output of your test

```
Static block of Class A
Non-Static block of a instance of Class A
Constructing object of type A
Non-Static block of a instance of Class A
Constructing object of type A
Static block of Class B
Non-Static block of a instance of Class B
Constructing object of type A
```

I guss you are surprised why `Static block of Class A` is printed only once. This is because the static block runs only once on class loading. After you called `new A()` 
JVM loaded A.class and when you called `new A()` again there was no need to load it again

Answer (score 1):

The static blocks are executed when the respective classes are initialized.

The order of class initialization is determined by a combination of the static and dynamic dependencies between the classes involved; see [When does static class initialization happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/java-static-class-initialization)

However, the JLS is effectively providing a set of constraints (this occurs before that) for which there are often many solutions.  And this is an example where two "solutions" to the constraints are possible.

1. The class `A` is initialized before the `new A()` expression constructs an `A`
2. The class `B` is initialized before the `new B()` expression constructs an `B`

As you can see, initialize class `A` before `B` and `B` before `A` are both solutions.

In a situation like this, the actual order of initialization is not specified, and is likely to be JVM and/or bytecode compiler dependent ... and should not be relied upon.

It is also possible to construct a scenario in which there is a cycle in the dependencies, which results in there being no order that satisfies the constraints.  In this case, the order is also indeterminate, and one of the classes *may* observe the other class in an uninitialized state.  (Neither the compiler or the runtime flags this as an error!)  This is described in JLS section [8.3.2.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.2.3).

Fortunately, this situation is pretty unusual.

---

Instance blocks and static methods are much simpler:

- The instance blocks of a class are executed in program order each time an instance is created.  They are executed in order between a constructor's `super(...)` "call" and the next line of that constructor.  (The same applies when the constructor is the default constructor and/or the `super()` call is implicit.)
- A static method is executed when it is explicitly called.

Answer (score 0):

following is the output of your program

```
Static block of Class A
Non-Static block of a instance of Class A
Constructing object of type A
Non-Static block of a instance of Class A
Constructing object of type A
Static block of Class B
Non-Static block of a instance of Class B
Constructing object of type A
```

Static block is called only once when first time class object is created