# Are enums initialized after other private static members defined in the class?

Tags: java, enums, initialization

I would like to write this pattern:

```
enum Foo {
  ABC(SHARED_DATA),
  DEF(SHARED_DATA);
  GHI(ImmutableList.of(4));

  private static final List<Integer> SHARED_DATA = ImmutableList.of(3);

  Foo(List<Integer> data) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  public static final List<Integer> data;
}
```

Am I guaranteed `SHARED_DATA` is initialized in time?

Comment: Did you look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619950/why-do-static-and-instance-init-blocks-in-enums-behave-differently-from-those-in or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11419519/enums-static-and-instance-blocks ?