# Why is my static var not initialized when accessing it through a static method?

Tags: java, static

I have the following Java class:

```
public class CWTokenMap {
    public static ConcurrentMap<String, String> allTokens
        = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

    public static void putTokenData(final String token, final String user) {
        allTokens.put(token, user);
    }
}
```

When I run my application, I try to access the `putTokenData` method from another class and I get a `NullPointerException` for the line `allTokens.put(...)`. Why do I get this exception?

It was my understanding that the static `ConcurrentMap` should be initialized by the time we access the `putTokenData` method, but here it seems to not be the case. Are there cases where the static method will be called before initializing the static variable?

Comment: Is either of your `user` or `token` is `null`?

Comment: Yes, token is null in the case I tested. I will test with a non-null token.

Comment: Is your debugger working? It would tell you. ;)

Comment: Not sure if this helps but you might take a look at this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/java-static-class-initialization

Comment: @MRenauld Always read the doc of the class you are using. This is clearly stated: _"Like Hashtable but unlike HashMap, this class does not allow null to be used as a key or value."_

Comment: Indeed, the null token was the problem. It seems I missed the part about the ConcurrentHashMap disallowing null keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not getting the `NPE` due to `allTokens`. That certainly would have been initialized, by the time the method is invoked. Perhaps you're passing `null` values for either `token` or `user` to the method. `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't allow `null` for either key or value.

Check the documentation of [`ConcurrentHashMap#put()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29) method:

> **Throws:**
>   `NullPointerException` - if the specified key or value is null

Comment: Really should have been `IllegalArgumentException`. :-/

Comment: @chrylis I also feel like so.

Answer (score 3):

> Are there cases where the static method will be called before initializing the static variable?

Yes, you can do this from a static initializer block.

```
static {
   callMethod(); // this will blow up as `c` has not been initialized yet.
}

static final Collection c = ...;

static void callMethod() {
    c.size();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) doesn't allow either the key or the value to be `null`, unlike some other `Map` implementations:

> Like `Hashtable` but unlike `HashMap`, this class does *not* allow `null` to be used as a key or value.

I suspect `token` or `user`, not `allTokens`, is the `null` in question.

Answer (score 0):

Yours statica variable is initialized, the problem as you write in the comment is that `token`, **the key of hasmap** is `null`..

**The key can't be null!!**

Read here [ConcurrentHasMap guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), as you can read:  **this class does NOT allow null to be used as a key or value.**

Answer (score 0):

[javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#put%28K,%20V%29)
says: "Throws: NullPointerException - if the specified key or value is null"