# Will static variable in non-instantiated class be initialized via call to Toolkit?

Tags: java, static-members, objectinstantiation

I want to be able to adjust click interval in a program IF the user wishes to do so, at which point class `ClickAdjustmentFrame` would be instantiated.

It had seemed sensible to have `CLICK_FREQUENCY` initialized in the only class where its value could be changed. So that class began like this :

```
public class ClickAdjustmentFrame {

    static int CLICK_FREQUENCY = ((Integer)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
      .getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval"));
```

Because that class isn't always instantiated, that class now imports the value of `CLICK_FREQUENCY` from the GUI class, where I moved the statement in question. (I.e., GUI now begins like this:)

```
public class GUI {

   static int CLICK_FREQUENCY = ((Integer)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
          .getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval"));
```

But before making the change, during debugging, it seemed that the call to `Toolkit` was being made even if `ClickAdjustmentFrame` had NOT been instantiated. At first that wasn't surprising. Then I began questioning the design and so moved the call to `Toolkit` to GUI.

It doesn't matter anymore in terms of my app, but for the record and for educational purposes, if the call to `Toolkit` were made nowhere else, WOULD THE VALUE OF `CLICK_FREQUENCY` BE COMPUTED and available to the rest of the package even if class `ClickAdjustmentFrame` (as shown below) were NOT instantiated?

```
public class ClickAdjustmentFrame {

    static int CLICK_FREQUENCY = ((Integer)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
      .getDesktopProperty("awt.multiClickInterval"));
...
```

I know that I could call a `static` method in a non-instantiated class (and do so quite often), but this is about `static` *variables* being initialized via a call to a `static` method somewhere else.

Exactly what very basic principle applies here? Is it that all `static` members of any class are available to other classes in the package?

Maybe a better question is this: Is it more sensible (better design) to move the call to `Toolkit` back to `ClickAdjustmentFrame`, the only class where the value of `CLICK_FREQUENCY` can be *changed*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static fields are initialised the first time the class is loaded by the classloader. See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/java-static-class-initialization).

For instance, if a static field of the class `ClickAdjustmentFrame` is accessed, there is no instance, but all static initialisations of the class will occur.

Comment: --That link is very good. Thanks. It really was a very basic question, wasn't it. Pretty obvious, now that I've read the link.