# java - static nested class lifetime

Tags: java, android, static-classes

1) when the lifetime of static nested class in Java begins?
can static inner class be used before creation of the containing object?

I'm asking because I encountered the code:

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

and I tried to answer the question:

2) what **is** LayoutParams **to** LinearLayout?

anyway if what I suspect doesn't relate to the syntax I would like to get answers for both 1 & 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java static class initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/java-static-class-initialization)

Comment: Is there a way I could know it? it looks to me like the syntax to create an object for a static nested class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An instance of a static nested class can be created without creating an instance of its outer class.

"static inner class" is an incorrect expression. JLS 8.1.3: An inner class is a nested class that is not explicitly or implicitly declared static.

LayoutParams is a static nested class of LinearLayout. LinearLayout is outer class of LayoutParams