# What is the difference of where System.LoadLibrary is placed?

Tags: android, java-native-interface

Here I have two ways to call System.LoadLibrary("XX.so"):

First way:

```
class SomeClass{
    static {
        System.LoadLibrary("XX.so");
    };

    public SomeClass(){
        ..
    };
}
```

The Other way:

```
class SomeClass{
        public SomeClass(){
            System.LoadLibrary("XX.so");
            ..
        };
    }
```

In most codes, I saw the first way is used. 
But second way also can run fine.

Do they have any difference between them ?

Comment: The first runs in static class initialization. The latter runs each time an instance of the class is created..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420389/static-initialization-blocks , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/java-static-class-initialization

Comment: @user2864740 ,the  only difference is the initialize time , and have no other effect. Is it ? Thanks for help