# Static block not executed without initialization

Tags: java, static-block

I have a question regarding static blocks:

Let's say i've got a class looking like this:

```
class SomeClass {
    static {
        System.out.println("static block");
    }
}
```

and I define a variable of type `SomeClass` somewhere.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SomeClass foo;
}
```

Now i thought the static block would have been executed but it wasn't. As far as i know the static block is executed as soon as the classloader loads the `SomeClass` class. Now to my real question:

**Isn't the class loaded as soon as I define a variable of that type?**. If yes why isn't the static block executed?

If the answer should be no, then how can i know if a class has already been loaded by the class loader and what are the different possibilities to have the class loaded (I know of 2: initializing the variable & using a static field/method)

Comment: The compiler could remove foo, the import of SomeClass in this case. `Class.forName("... SomeClass")` does initialize the class.

Comment: @JoopEggen ah ok, but couldn't the compiler also remove foo when it was initialized but never used? Or will the compiler never do that?

Comment: What if you do `SomeClass foo = new SomeClass();`

Comment: @Maraboc when i initialize foo with `new SomeClass()` then it will execute the static block

Comment: It is a common optimization for the compiler (and runtime) to delay loading classes until they are needed.  import statements are directives to the compiler, but are not executed at run time. I have seen environments where a class is loaded only when a method that references the class is executed but not when other methods that don't reference the class are executed.

Comment: @dsh so it's also depending on the compiler that is used?

Comment: Class.forName is overloaded with a boolean parameter to initialize the _class_; per default true. Initializing the _variable_ probably suffices to invoke class loading and initialization, even if the entire object is optimized away. One should consider that (ideally) there are more than one java compilers.

Comment: @JoopEggen many thanks! I think i got it now!

Comment: @ParkerHalo Yes. A naive compiler would not remove the unused variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Isn't the class loaded as soon as I define a variable of that type?.

Yes, it is loaded<sup>1</sup>, but it won't be initialized as a result of *declaring* a variable.  However, when you create an instance of that type, or access a static field of that type, that is sufficient to trigger initialization, including the execution of static blocks.

See this related Q&A - [When does static class initialization happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/when-does-static-class-initialization-happen/3499322#3499322) - which lists all of the things that can trigger initialization.

---

> How can i know if a class has already been loaded by the class loader and what are the different possibilities to have the class loaded (I know of 2: initializing the variable & using a static field/method)

The only ways I can think of for finding out when a class is loaded (as distinct from initialized) are:

- turning on the JVM's class loader messages (using `-verbose:class`), or
- using a customer classloader that notices, and does something appropriate when it sees a request to load the class.

A class is actually going to be *loaded*:

- when it is explicitly loaded using `Class.forName` or similar, or a direct call to a classloader,
- when it is necessary to load it in order to link another class, or
- at JVM launch time, if the class is named as the entry point class.

The loading / linking / initializing steps are specified in [Chapter 12 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html).

---

<sup>1 - In fact, `SomeClass` needs to be loaded at the same time that the class containing that `main` method is *linked*; i.e. before the method containing that local declaration is called.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

Refer to this doc: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077260/learn-java/learn-java-the-basics-of-java-class-loaders.html

> So when are classes loaded? There are exactly two cases: when the new bytecode is executed (for example, FooClass f = new FooClass();) and when the bytecodes make a static reference to a class (for example, System.out).

In your example, `SomeClass foo;` does neither execute the bytecode of SomeClass nor make a static reference to SomeClass. That's why the class is not loaded.

So following your example, add a static field in the class

```
public class SomeClass {
    static {
        System.out.println("static block");
    }

    static String abc = "abc";
}
```

SomeClass is loaded in either:

```
SomeClass foo = new SomeClass();
```

Or

```
System.out.println(SomeClass.abc);
```

Comment: Ermm .... the `SomeClass` class is >>loaded<<, but it isn't >>initialized<<, and class initialization is when the static blocks get executed.