# load class with Class loader in java by Class forName method

Tags: java, class

```
public class ClassLoaderTest {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {          
        //printing ClassLoader of this class
        System.out.println("ClassLoaderTest.getClass().getClassLoader() : "
                             + ClassLoaderTest.class.getClassLoader());


        //trying to explicitly load this class again using Extension class loader
        Class.forName("test.ClassLoaderTest", true 
                        ,  ClassLoaderTest.class.getClassLoader().getParent());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ClassLoaderTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

Class.forName has a second argument as true which indicates it will initialize a class in java.

What does class initialization means?

Comment: [Right there in [the JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-boolean-java.lang.ClassLoader-) it says *"initialize - if true the class will be initialized. See Section 12.4 of The Java Language Specification."* So [refer to §12.4 of the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialization phase of the class loading (loading, linking and initialization) includes executing static initializers and initialization of its static fields in textual order as defined in the class.

[When class initialization happen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/when-does-static-class-initialization-happen)

Answer (score 0):

execute *static code segment* and *initialize static filed* and some other relevant work, for more information see this.
[java class initialize](http://www.javaworld.com/article/3040564/learn-java/java-101-class-and-object-initialization-in-java.html)