# Are static initialisers necessarily executed in hierarchical order?

Tags: java, static, classloader, operator-precedence, static-initializer

Let's say I have a class

```
class A{
    public final static TreeMap<String,String> tmap = new TreeMap<>();
    int x;

    static{
        tmap.put("x:I", "Hello");
    }
}
```

and I create a subclass

```
class B extends A{
    long y;

    static{
        tmap.put("y:J","World");
    }
}
```

If I now write some code to check the static initialisers:

```
class Main{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        B b = new B();
        for(String v : b.tmap.values()){
            System.out.println(v);
        }
    }
}
```

I know both entries must be in `tmap` because `A` must get loaded, eventually, for `B`'s super call at the very latest.

But if I'm reading [When does static class initialization happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/when-does-static-class-initialization-happen?noredirect=1&lq=1) correctly, I *cannot* assume that the `Hello` value is put into the map first all the times because `tmap` is final.

So if ordering were important (say if I knew there's a chance some values may be updated/overwritten further down the hierachy), do I need to remove the `final` modifier?

Or is there something else already enforcing "proper" static initialiser ordering?

Comment: In your example the order by which the enties are added doesn't really matter since a TreeMap will automatically order them by the natural order of the key. A LinkedHashMap might work better as a example for this question.

Comment: Why do you think final has anything to do with the order?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis because the answer to the linked-to question emphasises that the static initialiser is called before the first use of a **non-constant** static field. static final fields *are* constant.

Comment: If you follow the JLS link in that answer, you'll see that it means a _constant variable_. A `final` and `static` field of type `TreeMap` is not a _constant variable_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static initialization is always done for the super class before the child is initialized, if you have multiple static initializer blocks, they are executed in order. (**Edit:** *Thanks to Holger for pointing out that this does not have to be directly when the class is loaded*).

In your example, B extends A, and the classloader therefore has to load A before B. Thus, the static initializer of A ist executed first.

This has nothing to do with the final modifier. What the other thread probably refers to is that if the compiler can perform constant folding( https://www.javaworld.com/article/2076060/build-ci-sdlc/compiler-optimizations.html), the class from which the constant is taken will not be static initialized (as the reference is replaced at compile time).

Comment: You meant "the classloader has to load ``A`` before ``B``"? Otherwise your conclusion that "the static initiliser of ``A`` is executed first" isn't exactly evident.

Comment: This is wrong. The initialization is not “done as soon as the class is loaded”. [The specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1) tells exactly, which events may trigger a class initialization. It’s perfectly possible that a loaded class’ initializer never runs. But thankfully, there’s the explicit statement, “*When a class is initialized, its superclasses are initialized (if they have not been previously initialized)…*”, so `A`’s initializer is indeed executed before `B`’s, but not because of your reasoning.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, for pointing that out. Fixed it in the answer