# Static Variable Initialization that reference each other?

Tags: java

This is somewhat related to static variable initialization order, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499214/when-does-static-class-initialization-happen) doesn't really answer my question.

When I run the following code, I expect undefined behavior or something with infinite recursion to happen:

```
class A {
    static File test = B.test;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         System.out.println(A.test);
         System.out.println(B.test);
    }
}
class B {
     static File test = A.test;
}
```

However, instead I see:

```
null
null
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Before it's set, the variable is null, and you never set either to anything other than null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer comes from [JLS section 12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4). We start with 12.4.1:

> 12.4.1. When Initialization Occurs
>
> A class or interface type T will be initialized immediately before the first occurrence of any one of the following:
>
> - T is a class and an instance of T is created.
> - A static method declared by T is invoked.
> - A static field declared by T is assigned.
> - A static field declared by T is used and the field is not a constant variable (§4.12.4).

When `A.main` is invoked, the third clause applies, and thus class A (and by extension `A.test`) must be initialized. The initialization of `A.test` triggers the fourth clause above, meaning that B must now be initialized. B must now access fields of A, but A has not yet initialized.

We need to now dig into section 12.4.2:

> 12.4.2. Detailed Initialization Procedure
> ...
> For each class or interface C, there is a unique initialization lock LC. The mapping from C to LC is left to the discretion of the Java Virtual Machine implementation. The procedure for initializing C is then as follows:
>
> 1. Synchronize on the initialization lock, LC, for C. This involves waiting until the current thread can acquire LC.
> 2. If the Class object for C indicates that initialization is in progress for C by some other thread, then release LC and block the current thread until informed that the in-progress initialization has completed, at which time repeat this step.
> 3. If the Class object for C indicates that initialization is in progress for C by the current thread, then this must be a recursive request for initialization. Release LC and complete normally.

Step 3 is the one we take here. Class A is already undergoing initialization by the current thread, so we are in a recursive initialization situation. We thus just give up and complete normally right away, so A.test remains null and B.test gets the value of A.test which is null.