# Java: common code for all constructors?

Tags: java, constructor

It seems to me constructors can share the same code, for example in:

```
public class Foo {
 private int foo;
 {foo = 5;}
 public Foo(){}
 public Foo(int v){this.foo = v;}
 public int getFoo(){return foo;}
}
```

The code "foo=5;" is called for both constructors.

It seems to me you can not, but I want to make sure. It not possible to create such common code that use parameters ?

eg, something like:

```
public class Foo {
 private int foo;
 (int m){foo = m*5;}
 public Foo(int m){}
 public Foo(int v,int m){this.foo = v;}
 public int getFoo(){return foo;}
}
```

To my understanding, the only way is to create a private void init(int m) to be called by all constructors ?

ps: I call {foo = 5;} "common code", but I guess this feature has another official name ?

EDITS (1):

1. The term I was looking for is initializer block
2. This question is not the same as asking if a constructor can also call another 
   constructor. Because when using an initializer block, the code is called AUTOMATICALLY, ie. without risk to call a constructor and forget to call it
3. My comment about using "void init" was not good, indeed in this case calling another constructor is better.
4. In short, my question: can an initializer block takes parameters ? Which would be kind of the same as forcing some parameters on all constructors to be implemented.

EDITS (2):

I now wonder if the only way to achieve what I am asking is to use inheritance to force  the use of a specific constructor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is this Java code in curly braces ({}) outside of a method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5865069/why-is-this-java-code-in-curly-braces-outside-of-a-method)

Comment: {}/common code is initializer

Comment: @Vince can you reword that? You can call other constructors from inside a constructor using `this(params p)` or `super()` (for the parent class).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I call one constructor from another in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285177/how-do-i-call-one-constructor-from-another-in-java)

Comment: please see my comment in the answer below. My question is slightly different.

Answer (score 6):

You can call your constructors from other constructors by calling `this()`, and matching the parameter list.

Say i have:

```
Foo(int a, int b) {
  // some code..
}
```

but i want to also call:

```
Foo(int a, int b, int c) {
  // some other code
}
```

I would say this:

```
Foo(int a, int b) {
  this(a, b, 0);
  // Whatever other code you want in this constructor.
}
```

Comment: Hi, my question is slightly different, as in my question the "common code" is automatically called, meaning no risk of creating a new constructor and forgeting the call to this(...). This being said, this answers perfectly my last comment (the only way is to use init() ...).

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand the way how Java creates objects!Assume the you have

```
class A{

private String b = "b";
private static String a = "a";

{
   b = "b2";
}

static{
 a = "a2";  
}

public A()
{
 b = "b3";
}


}
```

So the idea is that when you create an object

```
new A();
```

The first

```
private static String a = "a";
```

After

```
static{
 a = "a2";  
}
```

After

```
private String b = "b";
```

After

```
{
   b = "b2";
}
```

And only after

```
public A()
{
 b = "b3";
}
```

But be careful the priorities of static variables and static blocks are the same. And the priorities of normal variables and blocks are again the same. So if you put the next code

```
static{
 a = "a2";  
}
```

and after

```
private static String a = "a";
```

you will have that the code in the block is ignored, because you use the variable before declaration! And the same for normal variables!

Comment: By the way, in .Net the priority of fields higher than blocks so you can put block before declaration

Comment: Last paragraph is not correct. A static or instance initialization block that uses a forward reference to a variable declaration is not an error. Try it.

Comment: Yes but neither in a static nor in a normal block you will see assignment... so it looks like the variables are just ignored! I meat not a compile error I meant that it doesn't work.But it works in c#. So even if a block comes first the assignment happends

Comment: I cannot understand any of that, but your edit is still wrong. The block is not ignored, as you can easily verify for yourself. The initialised declaration causes *another* assignment. They are both executed, in the order they appear.