# When is the static block instantiated in a Java Class

Tags: java, static, static-block

Suppose there is a static block in a Class

```
public class Menu {

    private static Map<String, String> buttonEventMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    static {
        buttonEventMap.put("show-user","show");
        buttonEventMap.put("delete-user","delete");
    }

    public static Map<String, String> getHashMap() // To get the hash map
}
```

what is the life cycle of the block, when it will be instantiated, when the program starts or when we create the first object of the Class

Comment: Do we assume that `main` is outside of this class?

Comment: main will be outside the class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007666/in-what-order-do-static-initializer-blocks-in-java-run and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943556/static-block-in-java

Comment: A static initializer declared in a class is executed when the class is initialized (JLS - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.7)

Comment: Take a look at the comment by Dalee Bisen on http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/static-blocks.php

Answer (score 6):

It's executed when the class is initialized by the class loader. And the class is initialized lazily, the first time some code in the application needs this class (to call a static method, or to reference one of its static fields, or to create a new instance for example).

So if the program never uses the class, the static block will never be executed.

Comment: A fully precise statement is that it's executed when the class is **initialized**. Class loading can occur at any time the implementation sees fit, whereas class init must happen at the precise moment defined by the JLS.

Answer (score 2):

When you first access the class in your application.

Comment: Access means when we create the first object of the class ?

Comment: Yes typically. JB Nizet answered this already more completely.