# Accessing parent class static field using child class name doesn't load the child class?

Tags: java, inheritance, static

```
class A {
    static int super_var = 1;
    static {
        System.out.println("super");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    static int sub_var = 2;
    static {
        System.out.println("sub");
    }    
}
public class Demo{
    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(B.super_var);
    }
}
```

outputs are :

```
super
1
```

this means that the child class not going to load or any other thing? how is it works?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What output did you expect?

Comment: @RohitJain I suppose the static initialiser for `B` was expected to be called.

Comment: @boris yes that is what i expected

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you access the `static` fields of a super class on subclass reference, only the class that declares the field will be loaded and initialized, in this case it is `A`. This is specified in [JLS §12.4.1 - When Initialization Occurs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.1):

> A reference to a `static` field (§8.3.1.1) causes initialization of only
>   the class or interface that actually declares it, **even though it might
>   be referred to through the name of a subclass**, a subinterface, or a
>   class that implements an interface.

Emphasis mine.

So in your code, class `B` would not even be initialized, and hence its `static` block would not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the answer to this question: [In what order do static initializer blocks in Java run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007666/in-what-order-do-static-initializer-blocks-in-java-run)

The static block gets called only when a class is  accessed (either creating an instance or accessing a member field or static method). However, you access a member of class A only, so there is no reason for class B to be initialized yet. The static initializer of B will be called as soon as you access a member from that class (either a field or static method, or create an instance from class B).

The reason is that class B doesn't need to be initialized until you access one of its members. Because A doesn't know about B (and cannot access it) there's really no reason for B to initialize at that stage.

You will find out that when you access **B.sub_var** the static initializer of B will be executed.