# not able to access parent class object properties in child class in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

My question is pretty straightforward 
I have parent class and I have created a new driver object of webdriver class there 
In my subclass I am able to access the driver object but its value is null 
I am not able to access the object properties 
My parent Class is

```
public class BaseTest {

    public static  WebDriver driver;
    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void  VerifyPageTitle(String browser)
    {
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://chromedriver_win32(1)//chromedriver_win32//chromedriver.exe");
             driver = new ChromeDriver();
        }
        if(browser.equalsIgnoreCase("IE")){
            System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C://IEDriverServer_x64_3.3.0//IEDriverServer.exe");
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        }
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }
}
```

in my sub-class code

```
public class SignPageTest extends BaseTest{

    SignPage obj ;
    Boolean stu;
    @Test
    public void navigateToSignPage(){
    obj = new SignPage(driver);
    stu = obj.navigateToSignIn();
    }
    @Test(priority=2)
    public void getHandles(){
        stu = obj.handlingWindows();
    }

}
```

I am getting null-pointer as my driver is not initialized 
So please tell me the way to simply access the objects properties of super-class

the moment I make my driver as static I am able to access its properties  in all other classes but I don't want it to be static

Comment: at which line are you getting null pointer exception?

Comment: See the driver that I am able to acess in the sub-class is not even initialized the moment that object  is used to perform any operations
there would be null pointer
In my case its in my page class

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22582522/accessing-parent-class-static-field-using-child-class-name-doesnt-load-the-chil

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in your test code.

You are initialising a `WebDriver` instance via an `@BeforeTest` annotated method. TestNG invokes a `@BeforeTest` method only **ONCE** per `<test>` tag. So the below combination (which am guessing is what you have) will cause `NullPointerException` in the `@Test` methods of the second class.

- You have `SignPageTest` extend `BaseTest` and lets say you have another class called `SomeFlowTest` which also extends `BaseTest`
- You have created a `<test>` that includes both `SignPageTest` and `SomeFlowTest`.

This would cause the `@BeforeTest` to be executed only once for either `SignPageTest` (or) `SomeFlowTest` (depending upon the order in which they occur in your `<test>` tag), because both these classes extend from the same base class. So once TestNG executes `VerifyPageTitle()` via `SignPageTest` it will not execute the same method via `SomeFlowTest` and so the `WebDriver` instance for `SomeFlowTest` is null.

To fix this problem change `@BeforeTest` to either `@BeforeClass` (gets executed once per test class) or `@BeforeMethod` (gets executed for every `@Test` method).

Comment: You are 100% right , you have exactly told the problem I have tried that too but there is a problem with this practice , Ur new  driver will be created everytime so in this case for every class or method  new browser will be created I dont want the new browser be created , I want to use the same webdriver.

Comment: @abishekkachroo - If you want a WebDriver instance to be created once and shared everywhere else, then you should be trying to leverage a Singleton pattern, wherein the first invocation to it would cause the browser to be instantiated and all the rest of the calls would just use the already created ones. The creation call can be triggered from within a `@BeforeTest` method, and the rest of the code can just invoke the `getter()` method.