# Using Singleton in Constructor

Tags: java

I have a Singleton `Logger` class.

```
public class Logger {
  public static Logger INSTANCE = new Logger();

  private Logger() {
    ...
  }
}
```

I want to log in my constructor that a new instance is created. So my code looks like:

```
public class MyClass {
  public MyClass() {
    Logger.INSTANCE.log("MyClass created");
    ...
  }
}
```

I am wondering if this could break static instances of `MyClass`. For instance, if I have:

```
public class MyOtherClass {
  private static MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
  ...
}
```

I fear that this could cause a problem due to undefined order of initialization of static variables. So if `myClass` is initialized before `Logger.INSTANCE` is, then the construction of `myClass` will crash. Is there some mechanism to prevent this from happening or is using static variables in a constructor inherently dangerous? Is there any way to prevent users from creating static instances of `MyClass` in such a case?

Comment: If you must use a singleton pattern, the instance itself shouldn't be available. It should he wrapped in a method.

Comment: Note that in this case, your instance variable should be final and either private or protected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class Logger {
  public static Logger INSTANCE = new Logger();

  private Logger() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Is syntactic sugar for

```
public class Logger {
  public static Logger INSTANCE;
  static {
      INSTANCE = new Logger();
  }

  private Logger() {
    ...
  }
}
```

A static block sets up static members of the class, and [is guaranteed to run before your class is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007666/in-what-order-do-static-initializer-blocks-in-java-run).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to wrap your Logger.INSTANCE like in classic singleton:

```
public class Logger{

  private static Logger logger;

  private Logger(){

  }

  public static Logger getInstance(){
     if(logger==null){
         logger = new Logger();
     }
    return logger;
  }

}
```

This way when you will call `Logger.getInstance()` you will never get `null`.

**If you need thread safe singleton:**

```
public class Logger {
    private static class Holder {
        static final Logger INSTANCE = new Logger();
    }

    public static Logger getInstance() {
        return Holder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

This way you also will never get `null` because by default `Logger` will be initialized before class where it will be used, because in this case it will be dependency of other class.

Comment: Also, lazy loading isn't an explicit requirement.

Answer (score 0):

> So if myClass is initialized before Logger.INSTANCE is, then the construction of myClass will crash.

You can't initialise a class until all the classes it depends on have been initialised.

> Is there some mechanism to prevent this from happening or is using static variables in a constructor inherently dangerous?

You can't use a class before it has been initialised (unless you call it in the initialisation code)

> Is there any way to prevent users from creating static instances of MyClass in such a case?

You can't construct an instance of a class, until the classes it uses have been initialised.

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry about breaking anything, JVM will ensure the correct order of construction. However there is a risk multiple instances are created if accessed my many threads. Improve the code my declaring the singleton as final and using an static method to access:

```
public class Logger {
  private static final Logger INSTANCE = new Logger();

  private Logger() {}

  public static Logger getInstance() {
      return INSTANCE;
  }
}
```