# Android Thread Synchronization - synchronized keyword doesn't work?

Tags: android, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety

I'm using a singleton class SingletonA for my resources and I have a service ServiceS who uses the resources.

```
public class SingletonA {
    private static SingletonA ourInstance = new SingletonA();
    public static SingletonA getInstance() { return ourInstance; }
    private SingletonA () {}

    String resources;

    synchronized public void importSomething() {
        resources = "I have some value now";
    }
}

public class ServiceS extends Handler {
    private static ServiceS ourInstance = new ServiceS();
    public static ServiceS getInstance() { return ourInstance; }
    private ServiceS () {}

    SingletonA sa = SingletonA.getInstance();

    public void printResources() {   
        println(sa.resources);
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    SingletonA sa = SingletonA.getInstance();

    @override
    protected void onCreateBundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        sa.importSomthing();            
        ServiceS.printResources();
    }
}
```

-> In ServicesS class, sa value is **null** -> sa.printResources() causes **NPE**

However, since I add one more **sa = SingletonA.getInstance();** into ServiceS.printResources() like this:

```
public void printResources() {   
    sa = SingletonA.getInstance();
    println(sa);
}
```

-> **It worked**: sa != null and resources = "I have some value now".
Can someone explain for me why sa in ServiceS still null ? Thanks,

Comment: What does `getInstance` look like?  And what does `sa.length` look like?

Comment: I updated my question, thanks :D

Comment: I think that it's due to static initialization order. The static `ServiceS.ourService` is initialized before `SingletonA.ourInstance`.

Comment: Can you precise the initialization order in context of an simple app with singletons main thread and a timeout thread? Which is the first singleton? When timeout thread can start using the singletons?

Comment: See [here for more information on static initialization order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007666/in-what-order-do-static-initializer-blocks-in-java-run).  But the easy solution would be to just call `SingletonA.getInstance()` when necessary (vs caching in a member variable).  Or to lazily initialize `ServiceS.ourInstance` inside `getInstance`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment of Buddy:

it's due to static initialization order. The static ServiceS.ourService is initialized before SingletonA.ourInstance.

[See here for more information on static initialization order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007666/in-what-order-do-static-initializer-blocks-in-java-run). But the easy solution would be to just call SingletonA.getInstance() when necessary (vs caching in a member variable). Or to lazily initialize ServiceS.ourInstance inside getInstance